# Static assets aren't up to date in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, ruby-on-rails-3.2, redis

I have a static asset being served at `/assets/images/example.svg`. I made a change to this SVG in the codebase, and pushed to production.

It's not updated because I have static asset caching set up:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true

config.cache_store = :redis_store, "#{ENV['OPENREDIS_URL']}/0", { expires_in: 90.minutes }
```

And here's the response headers for the asset:
[image: Asset response headers]

I've run this command, which still doesn't expire my static assets:

```
heroku run rake tmp:cache:clear assets:clean:all assets:precompile
```

I've tried incrementing the `config.assets.version`, which didn't work either:

```
config.assets.version = '1.1'
```

How do you deal with static assets changing in the codebase? How do I manually expire my redis cache for a specific asset, or in general?

Comment: Not sure, but it could actually be a problem with git. Did you delete/replace the svg file? If so, maybe git ignored it when you staged your files (cp. `git add .` as opposed to `git add --all`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just wait another 30 minutes for it to expire. From what I understand, when you serve static assets on heroku you lose out on fingerprinting, meaning the cache would not be invalidated even if you change your assets version.

I recently went the way of putting everything on S3 using the [asset_sync gem](https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync). Everything has been incredibly peachy ever since.

Here's the configuration if you choose to go that route:

```
# Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
config.serve_static_assets = false

# Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
config.assets.compile = false

# Enable assets
config.assets.enabled = true

# Generate digests for assets URLs
config.assets.digest = true

config.action_controller.asset_host = "//your-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

In /config/environments/production.rb , try setting:

```
config.cache_classes = true
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.digest = true
```